# Jami conference software ruined any sound

Tags: sound, alsa

I use Ubuntu 22.04. While setting up Jami, a popup said I would get better sound by switching to ALSA. So I clicked the button to switch.

Now I have no sound on my computer in any program and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: There are several ways to install Jami. Please edit your question to make it clear exactly which path you followed.